# Why are project layout resources kept separate from Java sources?

Tags: java, maven, layout, resources

Why does maven keep resources in a separate "source folder" from the Java sources?

From my experience, in Java the resource files are mostly treated like Java source files which, when "compiled", just need to be copied as-is with the classes, and eventually packaged in the jar, and accessed by the *classloader*'s methods `getResource`/`getResourceAsStream`, via the `classpath`.

Personally I find it a useless complexity to keep resource files separate from Java sources.

1. What do you think?
2. Is there a good reason why maven keeps resources separate from sources?
3. Is there any counter indication in not using `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` and keeping 
   resources in `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` using maven?

Comment: This is a matter of subjective, personal opinion. You like it one way, someone else likes it another way. There's no good answer to the question what choice is best.

Comment: @Jesper, I see your point, but for this case, I think that this question can be answered; and the answer is that it's best to use maven conventions. There are lots of other cases where following convention is the best way to do things inside the context of the environment even though it may be possible to do it some other non-standard way. For example, it's best to put linux config files in `/etc`, it's best to put word docs inside `My Documents`, it's best to put a README file in the top level project dir, etc.

Comment: ...(ran out of room, so continuing comment here)... I think it's valid to argue that following convention is "best" unless there's some reason that provides more value to break the standard. And in this case, from experience, I agree with @Nishant's answer below and I can't think of any reason strong enough that would justify breaking the maven convention.

Comment: @Dave: I don't think the question here is primarily about whether it's best to follow their convention or not but more about why they chose that as the convention rather than something "simpler" like the traditional single source folder.

Comment: I agree that is best to follow conventions. But before maven introduced the convention of putting resources aside, the convention was to keep them with the source files. So, if it is best to follow the existing conventions, why maven introduced a new one if it doesn't bring any advantage? I think that having 4 or more source folders in your project doesn't make the work easier.
@ColinD: exactly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One point that hasn't been brought up yet is that you are obviously used to seeing projects with only java sources in them.  however, if you throw in some other source file types, i think the organization makes more sense, e.g.:

- src/main

  - resources
  - java
  - groovy

each sub-dir has a specific classification of files:

- java -> things that are compiled as java files
- groovy -> things that are compiled as groovy scripts
- resources -> uncompiled data used for whatever... (also, these may be filtered to add compile-time info)

also (as i've noted in some comments already), i don't usually make the resources directory flat.  files may be nested into a package-like structure or into other sub-directories as appropriate (to my sense of organization).

Comment: so what if I have some resources specific for the java code, and some resources with are specific to groovy code?

Comment: dunno, i've never personally felt the need to segment the resources (they are usually already separated into a package-like structure).

Comment: I agree with you here :) Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 10):

for simplicity and easier access we keep some resources as well in the java source path. This makes it convenient for us when developing on the GUI level as velocity templates and such are close to the Controller Java Code. But you have to tell maven to include non java stuff which is in src/main/java by adding something like this to your pom file.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                      <includes>
                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                        <include>**/*.htm</include>
                        <include>**/*.html</include>
                        <include>**/*.css</include>
                        <include>**/*.js</include>
                      </includes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                      <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/log4j.xml</exclude>
                      </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 8):

What do you think?
I think that the guys behind Maven should exercise a little "separation of concerns". The number one reason to use Maven is for dependency management, but why should a blender tell me how to peel my fruit? It makes no sense to me at all.

Is there a good reason why maven keeps resources separate from sources?
No. In a java project, the duplication of package structure, not once, but three times, adds unnecessary work to the project, increasing the risk for errors and reducing the agility of the code.

Comment: I quite agree with you. It's many years I'm using maven, I never felt any advantage to keep java classes separate from other resources accessible via classpath.
Instead I feel it correct having test code separate (since I want to exclude from the distribution package, runtime classpath, etc)

Answer (score 5):

I try to give an answer by myself.

> What do you think?

It's a useless additional complexity. Thus is wrong: see below.

> Is there a good reason why maven keeps resources separate from sources?

The only reason I might think of, is that for some platform this might be a good practice. For example in Mac OSX application, resources are packaged separately (in a different sub folder) than the binaries.

I think that "external" resources and configuration files, the ones that don't get packaged inside the final artifact (jar file) can have a good reason to be kept separate from the source files. So, when maven packages the jar, he knows that those files don't have to be included, because for example, we want them outside the jar in order to allow the user to edit those files as configuration.

But, for the things that are packaged together in the jar (like translation strings, and xml metadata, such as hibernate mappings and spring configuration) there is no good reason to have them in a separate location, unless we expect our users to change them manually after the deployment, as part of the configuration process.

Resources can be organized with the same package structure as for the classes, so if you have a class in the package x.y.z you may want to have the resources it depends on in the same package, as they represent the same "logical unit": in this case, having them in two separate folders leads to additional attention required during package refactoring and reorganization, since you want to keep the things in sync. The ClassLoader also provides the possibility to specify relative paths in the getResourceAsStream() method. So if you have the class x.y.z.MyClass, you can do getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo-bar.properties"), and the resources will be loaded from the same package "x.y.z". So it's very useful to keeps things together when they have a tight dependency.

For the **external** resources that needs to be kept separate also in the deployable artifact, it's a good thing to keep them separate, but in this case I don't see why maven treats the src/main/resources as a "java source folder" (maven-eclipse-plugin) since they actually must not be in the classpath but accessed through the filesystem as plain files, and especially you don't want those file to be included inside the jar during the maven build. This is the case of application icons, configuration files that you might want to place in /etc directory, and so on.

In conclusion, there's something wrong in how maven handles resources, in my opinion: if they are "external" resources, then there's no reason why maven packages them in the final artifact (jar). If they are not "external", then there is no reason to keep them in a separate "source folder".

> Is there any counter indication in not using src/main/resources and src/test/resources and keeping resources in src/main/java and src/test/java using maven?

I don't know.

Most of the time I've used the default maven layout to play with resources, but in a couple of times I didn't; taking the precaution to declare the non-standard resources directory location in the pom (see [resources](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) and [super-pom](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM)). 
It is possible to alter the maven project's directory structure specifying that in the pom:

```
 <build>
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
  </build>
```

And I didn't find particular problems with it.

I would like that maven guys think again about this convention, as having a simpler project structure helps the developer to concentrate more on the development and less on finding things around several folders in the project structure while browsing the application code.

Answer (score 2):

The way I distinguish between the two is that the `java` folders default to allowing nothing to be built in the resulting jar, except the file types I list (e.g. `*.class`, `*.html`, `*.properties` if you're using Wicket), whereas all the stuff in `resources` will be copied in the build except the few exceptions I list.

Of course that's just my private convention, adhered to by myself.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) What do you think?

I thinks, it's an excellent convention.

> 2) Is there a good reason why maven keeps resources separate from sources?

Yes. You follow the convention. Everyone, who has got your project code's access will know where to look for code and where for everything else. And certainly, where for test cases. And what will happen to which file when that plugin will be executed.

> 3) Is there any counter indication in not using src/main/resources and src/test/resources and keeping resources in src/main/java and src/test/java using maven?

There isn't a counter indication. It's matter of convention, nothing's wrong with the way you arrange your *own* code. In fact, if you ever created a Wicket project, you will see your HTML and your Java code stays side-by-side in Java package. But, it is just Wicket where you know the HTML is going to be by the side of Java files. But everything else goes in `resources` folder.

Comment: I don't think you've provided a good answer for question 2. The question is essentially "why is maven's convention of using a separate resources folder good", and you basically answer that with "because it's a convention". Why that convention though, and not something else that might be (in some people's eye) simpler?

Comment: @ColinD I have come from ANTs world to Maven world and I have seen 10s of different convention in ANT builds.. and they all have good reason to explain the folder structure. The idea is _understandable separation of concern_. One project in ANT that, I had early on, had core/java, core/ui, core/settings, staging/classes, staging/output, test/ -- It makes sense as well. I just did not want to dive in argument by mentioning separation of concerns because people will come-up with other patterns that fit-in correctly as well.

Comment: about 2., if you don't explain why it is good, you cannot say that is good to follow just "because it's a convention". with a an answer like this, any convention is good just because it's a convention: no matter if it is good or not.

Comment: Then why not having separate folders for xml, properties, icons, pictures, xsd, sql, text, etc? If we care not to mix java source code with "everything else" why shouldn't we care to mix properties files with xml files? will this make it easier or harder to handle?

Comment: @Luigi: Technically, "configuration" type files should probably go under `src/main/config` according to the standard directory layout. In any case, any kind of standard structure is going to be arbitrary to some degree... the people who designed it came up with a set of groups for source files to go in and they chose a level of granularity that they thought seemed appropriate. It doesn't please everyone, but it's at least relatively easy to understand when you look at it.

Comment: @Luigi R. Viggiano right, this is exactly sort of conversion I was avoiding. The pattern that Maven uses is one of the best patterns in making things modular. You can certainly come with one of your own which is more correct and suitable for your project. But the pattern that Maven is like one-size-fit-all.

Comment: @Luigi R. Viggiano - there's no reason you wouldn't separate these resource files under the resource dir, e.g. resources/xml, resources/icons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm the only one here who does not come from a Java background. I think that mixing resources and code is very messy. Separation of concerns make your project cleaner and easier to understand/maintain as it grows.

I try to apply my own directory convention to all my software development projects:

- bin: final binaries used by user
- build: intermediate binaries, they may be deleted after build
- lib: external libraries
- src: ONLY source code (in this case, Java source files)
- resources: all resources (configuration files, xmls, images, html, etc)
- docs: documentation

Rarely I've found a development context when I needed to change this directory structure.

Using Maven, if you want to make a quick setup, use the defaults. If you want to use your directory convention, you just need to change settings in the pom.xml as explained before. Be aware, however, that some Maven plugins consider you use default Maven directories for resources/source/output binaries and you'll need to adjust some plugin settings if you change these directories.

Comment: why do you consider xml not being "source code", for example? same question can be done for html and (some kind of) configuration files.

Comment: XML is just static data (at least they were created with this purpose). There is no way to perform branching and loops, as any programming language would. HTML is trickier; they are in the borderline dependending if there is embedded javascript or not. I do never put code inside configuration files, as this mixes data and code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that code/resources separation is often useful:

1. Packages must follow Java specification rules, for example reserved word, like 'int', is not allowed. Having illegal packages in source code folder would be confusing.
2. Resources has instance nature, classes has, well, classes nature. For example you may have classes `Continent` and `Country` in the same package but resources better organize as tree:

   - africa/

     - morocco.txt
     - kenya.txt
   - europe/

     - poland.txt
3. Resources structure, in my opinion, is more stable than code structure. Code refactoring happens often, classes move from package to package for better readability. Obligation to move resources on refactoring discourages developer from refactor.
4. If separated resource folder is required even only for 1% of resource files, is reasonable to move remaining 99% to that folder and keep resources in single place only.

However, there are cases when keeping resources and java code together is useful. For example unit tests compares input and output - nice to have file with input and output in the same folder as unit test code.