# Java project layout - can it be simple?

Tags: java, maven, layout, gradle

Our project are built from a lot of relatively small components which use different languages - java, sql, pascal. Each component has its own repository and its own function scope

So we never

- mix programming languages
- mix functionality

Most new components use [maven structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), some  java legacy components use very simple structure, they have only "src" and "test" folders and resource files are kept near java files. And it is turned out that it is very convinient! May be I'm missing something?

Question - what is rationale, for the circumstances I mentioned above, to have recommended maven structure, why not simply:

- ["src/main/java", "src/main/resources"] => "src"
- ["src/test/java", "src/test/resources"] => "test"

Ref. also [Why are project layout resources are kept separate from Java sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830547/why-are-project-layout-resources-are-kept-separate-from-java-sources)

Comment: Well, the question that you refer to really isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow, and this should tell you that yours will not have a clear answer, either. Basically, do what you please. If you need to use Maven, you need to stick by its rules. If you don't, do what's convenient for your organization.

Comment: Maven does not prevents you from using your own directory layout. You can do whatever your opinion is. This question will lead to opinion based answers

Comment: I wonder if not gradle or ivy would fit better in this scenario? I would stick with maven layout if I use maven. Look at options I mentioned and see if they fits your codebase better.

Comment: "I wonder if not gradle or ivy would fit better in this scenario?" - good note, actually we use gradle, but with default maven layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Convention Over Configuration" and this is the core design concept of Maven. In my opinion, it's just a rule and a standard. Because there are HTTP protocol, you can choose a different browser, such as IE and Firefox. The most important reason is that the use of conventions can greatly reduce the configuration. You can also define your own file directory in maven, like Ant, if you are dealing with legacy code, and can not change the original directory structure, then only let Maven compromise. But apart from that, you have no reason to do so, ["src/main/java", "src/main/resources"] => "src" will make the problem more complicated, not simply, because this can cause communication problems, in addition to you, others do not know why to do so.Such as IE compatibility issues, It's terrible.

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.*.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <!-- This told maven that the source is in src/java, no src/main/java -->
        <sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, if simplifying structure makes development more complicated  then there is no reason to simplify. That's what I call rational argument. But in my practice maven structure requires more efforts, in particular for handling resources for Java files which are kept seperately from the sources.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer your question without knowing specification of your project/components.

My suggestion will be:

If you have any additional files such as configuration files (ie logger config file, database config file etc), resources (images, document templates, etc), go with Maven recommended structure and put those files under resources, so separate them from code.
That will make your

If from other hand you don't have anything like those files, go with your simple structure.

Comment: Agree, this is quite reasonable

Answer (score 0):

My own answer. Standart maven structure is needed when we mix languages and functionality in one component (one VCS repository), examples:

- [Case 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830547/why-are-project-layout-resources-are-kept-separate-from-java-sources) (ref. answer)
- [Case 2](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/goobi-production/+spec/standard-project-structure)

In these scenarious such structure is indeed helpful, its function is to separate files which are processed differently by different tools.

If it is not the case then simpler structure may be used.

Comment: Even with 5 different language you can keep all in the same directory if you like. With Gradle e. g. you can easily define patterns of what to include for what, so e. g. `src/**/*.java` as Java source files `src/**/*.cpp` as C++ files, everything else as resource files. It is totally up to you how you layout your files. Gradle just follows the recommended conventional structure of Maven by default, as it has proved useful, and many people coming from Maven are used to it and it also makes switch from Maven to Gradle easier.

Comment: "It is totally up to you how you layout your files" - of course! But I think there are also rational reasons to follow particular structure.