# Java getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename)

Tags: java, maven, classloader

I have a Maven project. My entire code is in the folder {PROJECT_ROOT}/src/main/java. When I write the code:

```
InputStream input = VertxApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
String result = getStringFromInputStream(input);
System.out.println(result);
```

I see that the code looks for the file named "file.txt" in the folder: 
{PROJECT_ROOT}/src/main/resources.

My question is why. Why doesn't it look for files in {PROJECT_ROOT}/src/main/java or in ${PROJECT_ROOT} for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Maven projects follow the structure of

```
src/
  main/
    java/
    resources/
```

You're intended to keep your non-code resources separate from your code. The `getResourceAsStream` method assumes this standard is followed, so it looks for your resource starting from the `resources/` directory.

See [Why are project layout resources are kept separate from Java sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830547/why-are-project-layout-resources-are-kept-separate-from-java-sources) for some more detailed thoughts.

Comment: OK. There are also other objects that get file path as an input, such as File and FileInputStream. For them, the path is relative to the {PROJECT_ROOT}. When I have to give an input path to a file, how can I know if the path is relative to PROJECT_ROOT or to PROJECT_ROOT/src/main/resources ? 
Is there any function that returns the base path?

Comment: @CrazySynthax  That's why we have something called *absolute path*

Comment: @CrazySynthax In general the path is only relative to `src/main/resources` if the method is specifically related to loading a resource, such as `getResourcesAsStream`. Normally, paths are relative to where the application is run from (the current working directory). For Maven, it seems that everything is run from, and relative to, the project root.

Comment: Actually, the path is relative to some classpath entry. It's not because Maven or Java "know" the file is a resource. That's just plain silly. It's because the correct directory happened to be found in the classpath. If the first entry hadn't contained the requested resource, the system would have tried the next, and so on. Study up on classpath.

Answer (score 1):

When you build a maven project or run it from an IDE supporting maven, the java files from `src/main/java` are compiled to class files and put in `PROJECT_ROOT/target/classes`.

The files from `src/main/resources` are copied to `PROJECT_ROOT/target/classes` as well.

When you call `VertxApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt")` you get the classloader for the `VertxApp` class and this classloader will try to load the given resource from the path where the class was loaded from.

If your `VertxApp`class is in the top package, the the class file will be in  `target/classes`and the resource will be searched there as well as you specify a relative path of `"file.txt"`, therefore you must put it in `src/main/resources`.

If the `VertxApp`class is for example in a package named `mypackage`then the class file would be in `target/classes/mypackage` and you should have the file in `src/main/resources/mypackage` so that it ends up in `target/classes/mypackage`as well.

If you have the `VertxApp`class in a package but want to keep the file in `src/main/resources`(without a subdirectory), you must reference it as an absolute path like this:

```
VertxApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt")
```

Comment: It's not 100% accurate. 
I put "file.txt" in src/main/resources and after compilation, "file.txt" was found under target/classes. 

The code that loads this resource is inside a package named "examples". After compilation "file.txt" was under target/classes and the classes of the java files were under target/classes/examples.

In addition, when I call "getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");" I name the file as relative path (without the "/")